# Python: normalize values in range (0... infinity) to (0...1). Output is identical for all rows in dataframe when inputs are unique

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, normalization

I found a question that gives an equation to normalize, but doesn't address syntax:

**Question:**
[Normalize any value in range (-inf…+inf) to (0…1). Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140347/normalize-any-value-in-range-inf-inf-to-0-1-is-it-possible)

**Equation I want to use:**

```
(1 + x / (1 + abs(x))) / 2
```

In my dataframe, the output is identical all the way down my new `'normalized_column'`, even though the input variables in my `'not_normalized_column'` are unique.

I'm accessing the values by column name: `'not_normalized_column'`.

What is the best way to perform the operation for all values in the column? Thanks!

**Here is my (failed) code:**

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = r"C:\Users\kevin\Desktop\file.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)


for x in df['not_normalized_column']:
    df['normalized_column'] = (1 + x / (1 + abs(x))) / 2
```

**output:**

```
print(df.head(20))

    not_normalized_column  normalized_column
0                1.192575           0.866625
1                1.517879           0.866625
2                1.550685           0.866625
3                1.680974           0.866625
4                1.600331           0.866625
5                1.600675           0.866625
6                1.599243           0.866625
7                1.577447           0.866625
8                1.546771           0.866625
9                1.513165           0.866625
10               1.481408           0.866625
11               1.446590           0.866625
12               1.415659           0.866625
13               1.386197           0.866625
14               1.355200           0.866625
15               1.335662           0.866625
16               1.321336           0.866625
17               1.316952           0.866625
18               1.306000           0.866625
19               1.302547           0.866625
```

Comment: @JCSommer I have edited the question to reflect the new problem once I corrected the bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a bracket:

try run this, that should work:

```
for x in range(-2000,2000, 300):
    y=(1 + x / (1 + abs(x)))/2
    print(y)
```

In reply to your updated question:
What you want to do to this is to use **.apply**:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'not_normalized_column': [-1000, 1000], 'normalized_column': [None, None]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print("This is the toy dataframe before running the normalization:\n",df)
    
df['normalized_column'] = df['not_normalized_column'].apply(lambda x: (1 + x / (1 + abs(x))) / 2)
    
print("\n This is the toy dataframe after running the normalization:",df)
```

Comment: thanks... your code ran well, but it didn't answer my question. How do I apply this to get the new column in my dataframe. I ran this in the format posted in my question and got an identical answer for the entire column (which should have unique inputs).

Comment: @cowboykevin05 I updated my answer to reflect the new problem :)

Comment: @cowboykevin05 Do you have more questions? If not, can you accept one of the answers?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing something similar. I used the 'transform' function instead of 'apply' as I'm dealing with groups of data. Although it was probably unnecessary in this case... the output is the same in both cases. Much appreciated! ALTHOUGH I don't think this will deal with the value infinity 'inf' ... Still trying to figure that out. I probably should've included that in my sample dataset. --- I do have 'inf' values in my full dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the overall answer but you're getting a Syntax Error and I can see a syntax problem.

You're missing a closing parenthesis in the last line of your code after the 2.
Try that first

Comment: Thanks @ejooco. I was missing a bracket but not at the end. I'll edit my question.... As I still have an issue with the code running properly. It's not giving an error anymore, but is giving an identical output for every row in that new column.